# What is the benifit of make_unique or make_shared in C++?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I saw in this [cppcon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sQCSX7vmmKY&t=2710s) that make_unique/make_shared are supposed to be faster but in the following program I ran in VSCode and compiled with g++ gives me different result.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

size_t len = 10000000;
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    int* tmp(new int(i));
    delete tmp;
  }
  std::chrono::duration<double> dur = std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start;
  std::cout << "int* = " << dur.count() << "\n";

  start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    std::unique_ptr<int> tmp(new int(i));
  }
  dur = std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start;
  std::cout << "std::unique_ptr = " << dur.count() << "\n";
  
  start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    std::unique_ptr<int> tmp = std::make_unique<int>(i);
  }
  dur = std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start;
  std::cout << "std::make_unique = " << dur.count() << "\n";
  
  start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    std::shared_ptr<int> tmp(new int(i));
  }
  dur = std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start;
  std::cout << "std::shared_ptr = " << dur.count() << "\n";
  
  start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    std::shared_ptr<int> tmp = std::make_shared<int>(i);
  }
  dur = std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start;
  std::cout << "std::make_shared = " << dur.count() << "\n";
  
  return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
int* = 0.709534
std::unique_ptr = 1.12149
std::make_unique = 1.14068
std::shared_ptr = 1.7354
std::make_shared = 2.13896
```

Can anyone please explain the mystery behind?

Comment: Read item 21 from Effective Modern C++, Scott Mayers explained very well.

Comment: When profiling code, always mention your compiler and its optimization settings. Profiling unoptimized code is meaningless

Comment: How did you compile your code?  Were all optimizations enabled?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/joeGYY9Kq

Comment: For me the benefits are, less memory managment bugs. And they work exceptionaly well with exceptions ;) The small performance hit (in time) is usually totally worth it (from a maintenance point of view).

Comment: The benefit is that you can make "no `new` and `delete` outside of containers and smart pointers" a strict rule. It helps with reducing memory leaks.

Comment: What optimization level did you compile your performance testing code?

Comment: The difference is `make_shared` makes 1 heap allocation, and `shared_ptr(new...)` makes 2. Read the dupes for more details.